# About Session in wicket 6

Tags: session, wicket-6

Now i'm studying wicket.I'm using wicket 6.But I can't get the HttpSession with wicket 6.In wicket's old version,

```
HttpSession session = ((ServletWebRequest)RequestCycle.get().getRequest()).getHttpServletRequest().getSession();
```

is used to get session.But in wicket 6, the method does not exist even more.
By the way , in wicket,in a same application pages information was stored in session,and how could I get them.

Answer (score 6):

This works in Wicket 6:

```
HttpSession session = ((ServletWebRequest) RequestCycle.get().getRequest()).getContainerRequest().getSession();
```